# Search Toolbar Textbox not appearing in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying the jqGrid for the first time. I need to show Toolbar search filter. But it is never showing the search Textbox in the toolbar.

Below is my code,

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" />


<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery().ready(function(){
    jQuery("#list2")
            .jqGrid({
                url: 'server.php',
                datatype: "json",
     colNames: ['Product Id', 'Product Name', 'Supplier Id', 'Unit Price'],
                colModel: [{
                    name: 'productid',
                    index: 'productid',
                    search: true,
                    width: 55
                }, {
                    name: 'productname',
                    index: 'productname',
                    width: 90
                }, {
                    name: 'supplierid',
                    index: 'supplierid',
                    width: 100
                }, {
                    name: 'unitprice',
                    index: 'unitprice',
                    width: 80,
                    align: "right"
                }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager2',
                sortname: 'productid',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "JSON Example"
            })
    });

    jQuery("#list2")
            .jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', {
                edit: false,
                add: false,
                del: false
            });

jQuery("#list2").jqGrid
  ('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});

</script>
```

I am using the 4.4.1 version. I have checked the Custom Additinal methods checkbox whilst downloading.

Am I missing any js files?

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake. I am placing the call to filterToolbar out of the ready function. it should be inside the ready function.

Fixed

Sorry for this question but still I will not delete this as this kind of mistakes are common I guess.. so its helpful for those kind... ;-)